# Date range picker send selected date with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, daterangepicker

[Date range picker.](http://daterangepicker.com)

I am trying to send selected date with Ajax, but I get error:

```
  $(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      startDate: moment(),
        showDropdowns: true
      },
      function(start,end, label) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"date": start},
            dataType: 'html',
            method: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
            }
        })
    });
  });
```

For some reason I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with a library you're using there. Have you looked up through the call stack at all?

Comment: Hi David, I don't think so. If I remove .ajax part, and I add alert(start); after function(start,...) then it is working.

Comment: Maybe the "start" is not available from the other function (.ajax)?

Comment: `start` is a moment object. What does it mean to POST a moment object to process.php? Isn't process.php expecting some specific kind of string or timestamp? Why don't you send it that instead.

Comment: Hi Dan, good question. process.php is expecting a date for SQL statement: `"WHERE date_created >= '". $_POST['date'] ."'";` How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Adrian your screenshot definitely shows the error happening in moment.min.js - so what is being done to call a function from that library?

Comment: @DavidMillar the AJAX call is no doubt trying to serialize `start` to a string since he's trying to send it in the POST body. `start` is a moment object. I don't know why that would be causing an error though.

Comment: @Adrian `var date_as_string = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @DanGrossman excellent. Can you please write an answer under the question, so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` is a moment object and what your PHP code expects is a string. I'm not sure why `moment` is giving you that error when serializing the object, but perhaps converting it to a string yourself will fix it:

```
var date_as_string = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```